# Why my password didnt encrypt in the database by using AES encryption?

Tags: vb.net, aes, password-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I want to encrypt my password using AES but it saves as plain text in the database. Ive run some codes by using the example given in the internet and it did encrypt the plain text in the database. i dont know why it cant implement in my coding. Help me to encrypt the password :)

Here is what i have tried so far:

```
Private Function Encrypt(clearText As String) As String
    Dim EncryptionKey As String = "MAKV2SPBNI99212"
    Dim clearBytes As Byte() = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText)
    Using encryptor As Aes = Aes.Create()
        Dim pdb As New Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, New Byte() {&H49, &H76, &H61, &H6E, &H20, &H4D, _
         &H65, &H64, &H76, &H65, &H64, &H65, _
         &H76})
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32)
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16)
        Using ms As New MemoryStream()
            Using cs As New CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
                cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length)
                cs.Close()
            End Using
            clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())
        End Using
    End Using
    Return clearText
End Function

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        Dim cn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("xxxx").ConnectionString
        Using cs As New SqlConnection(cn)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM zzzz")
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                    Dim dt As New DataTable()
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Connection = cs
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub btnSubmitAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmitAdd.Click 'FUNCTION IS EXECUTED WHEN BUTTON SUBMIT IS CLICKED


    If Request.Form("pass1") = Request.Form("pass2") Then 'CHECK IF FIRST AND SECOND PASSWORD IS THE SAME
        cs.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO zzzz (user_id, user_name, user_password, user_rank, user_section, user_securitycode) VALUES ('" & Request.Form("userid") & _
                "','" & Request.Form("name") & "','" & Request.Form("pass1") & "','" & Request.Form("privilege") & _
                "', '" & Request.Form("section") & "', '" & Request.Form("user_securitycode") & "')" 
        cmd.Connection = cs
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_password", Encrypt(Request.Form("pass1")))
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cs.Close()
```

Comment: Oh, dear! Sql injection.

Comment: if i change the way ive inserted the data into the database to avoid the sql injection, will it encrypt my password?

Comment: I am working on an answer. Hold on.

Comment: really? omg, thank you so much.

Comment: I see Mary has given you a good answer, but the reason it's storing the plain password is that the line `"','" & Request.Form("name") & "','" & Request.Form("pass1") & "','" & Request.Form("privilege") & _` should have been `"','" & Request.Form("name") & "',@user_password,'" & Request.Form("privilege") & _` to use the parameter (I may have some quotes wrong in there).

Comment: @3b4 I recommend that you read [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Answer (score 2):

You did so well with local database objects and `Using` blocks in the `Page.Load`. I am sorry to see you dropped it for this button code. Although, I don't see the point of hauling down all that data in the `Page.Load` and then discarding it without use.

Each value from the Insert should be set up as a `Parameter`. Failure to do this is what can open the door for sql injection. I see that you tried to do this with the password, only there was no parameter named `"@user_password"` in your Insert statement. This is why it didn't get encrypted.

The `.Add` method is preferable to `.AddWithValue` for Sql Server. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

I had to guess at the datatypes and field size of the parameters. Check you database for the actual values and adjust the code accordingly. If a parameter is a number type, be sure to convert the `.Value` variable to the proper type.

I am a bit concerned about userid. How can a new user have a userid? I suspect that this field is the primary key of your table and is an identity field (auto-increment). You do not include identity fields in your field list or try to pass any value for an Insert.

I know very little about web apps, but `Request.Form("name")` looks strange to me. I would think these would be just `Request("name")`.

```
Private Sub btnSubmitAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmitAdd.Click 'FUNCTION IS EXECUTED WHEN BUTTON SUBMIT IS CLICKED
    Dim insert = "INSERT INTO zzzz (user_id, user_name, user_password, user_rank, user_section, user_securitycode) VALUES (@userid,@name,@password,@privilege,@section,@securityCode)"
    If Request.Form("pass1") = Request.Form("pass2") Then 'CHECK IF FIRST AND SECOND PASSWORD IS THE SAME
        Using cs As New SqlConnection(cn),
                cmd As New SqlCommand(insert, cs)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CInt(Request.Form("userid"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Request.Form("name")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Encrypt(Request.Form("pass1"))
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@privilege", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Request.Form("privilege")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@section", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Request.Form("section")
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@securityCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Request.Form("user_securitycode")
            cs.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

I didn't even look at your encryption code. The question was about why your password didn't encrypt and I hope I answered that.

Comment: full of explanation and i really appreciate. new lesson today! i will try to change it and thank you so much, mary.